# Nginx: how to link single subdomain to wildcard ssl, all others to http?

Tags: nginx, ubuntu

Working on an AWS Ubuntu server.

I have a bunch of vhosts (nginx records) representing subdomains for `example.com` that are all using http instead of https. I want to add a wildcard ssl certificate so that we can simply add a subdomain to use https whenever we want, and keep all the others using only http.

What is the proper setup configuration for this? I'm new to nginx and working on a server built by another person.

Comment: Just configure SSL only for the domain you want.

Comment: is this possible if we must use a wildcard ssl for ```*.example.com```? If we did, I assume that forces all subdomains to have ssl.

Comment: Of course it is possible. Does it make sense? Most probably not. Why would you only want SSL only for a single domain, especially when you already have a wildcard certificate. The usage of SSL increases every day, browsers are turning towards HTTPS first. There is absolutely no reason nowadays to only provide HTTP.

Comment: I realize it does not make sense, but most of these http subdomains have a custom encryption system to provide security. as I mentioned before, I didn't build this system. IMO it certainly makes no sense, but i have to adjust for it. We can't immediately change all domains to use https, so I need to gradually migrate by activating a wildcard ssl on the root domain, and only apply the ssl to one subdomain at a time, that is what i don't know how to do